# Using LIKE %...% in Drupal 7, Views 3

Tags: views, database

**I'm trying to change** the Views SQL operator from `= 'String'` to `LIKE 'String%'`.

**I thought the best way to do this was** through `function hook_views_pre_execute(&$view)` at the bottom of `views.module`. I tried that, but any way I edited the query it would throw an error.

For example, I tried str_replace:

```
function views_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == "schools")
    {
        $view->build_info['query'] = str_replace("location.city = :db_condition_placeholder_3","location.city LIKE '".$view->build_info['substititions']['%2']."'",$view->build_info['query']);
    }
}
```

I expected this code to edit the query so it would search `location.city LIKE 'Calgary%'`, but instead I got `Fatal error: Call to a member function addMetaData() on a non-object in [...]/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_query_default.inc on line 1306`.

**I [read the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/54455)**, but it looks like when they refer to Wildcards like %1 and %2, they're referring to arguments passed as contextual filters, as opposed to an SQL LIKE %...% wildcard.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wound up using the [Computed Field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to create a custom SQL query.